# Densheild boards and 12"X24" tile

Tags: shower, tile, bathtub, support, backer-board

Can Densheild boards hold a 12"X24" porcelain tile? ( *the tiles are for shower walls* ).

Someone told me that the top layer of the boards are paper and installing the tiles on the higher area with this size might fall down later ( *the height of the area to be tiled is 5'*)

Comment: Does one 12" x 24 tile weigh more then eight 6"x 6" tiles ?  Was the "someone" a Denshield representative? Unlikely that "someone" is correct.

Comment: No when I was thinking to buy at the beginning the green board from lowes the person there suggested that I buy the cement board as the green board is paper at the end and it might not hold 1'X1' tile that they were selling

Comment: This is the manufacture reply: " Thank you for your interest in Georgia-Pacific Gypsum products. We do not have a tile size maximum, however the weight of ceramic tile applied directly over gypsum panel products on vertical surfaces using thin-set adhesive shall not exceed 6.5 psf."

Comment: The 12X24 weight is 6.8 pound and its 2 sqft size therefore 1 sqft weight is 3.4 pound, It should be ok to use it with densheilds board right?